# How to fix: jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'csrf_token' is undefined

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm  running code in Python (I found it already built from a tutorial). I want to deploy the model on a web app (using Flask)

When I run my app I get the following error, see the traceback below:

> jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'csrf_token' is undefined

Traceback:

```
  File "/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 780, in handle_exception

reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)

  File "/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/_compat.py", line 37, in reraise

    raise value.with_traceback(tb)

  File "/Users/usersname/Desktop/flaskSaaS-master/app/templates/uploaded.html", line 1, in top-level template code

    {% extends "layout.html" %}

  File "/Users/usersname/Desktop/flaskSaaS-master/app/templates/layout.html", line 94, in top-level template code

    {% block content %}{% endblock %}

  File "/Users/usersname/Desktop/flaskSaaS-master/app/templates/uploaded.html", line 8, in block "content"

    <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>

jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'csrf_token' is undefined

127.0.0.1 - - [06/Oct/2019 19:57:32] "GET /upload.php?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -

127.0.0.1 - - [06/Oct/2019 19:57:32] "GET /upload.php?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -

127.0.0.1 - - [06/Oct/2019 19:57:32] "GET /upload.php?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=debugger.js HTTP/1.1" 200
-

127.0.0.1 - - [06/Oct/2019 19:57:32] "GET /upload.php?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=console.png HTTP/1.1" 200
-

127.0.0.1 - - [06/Oct/2019 19:57:32] "GET /upload.php?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=console.png HTTP/1.1" 200
-

127.0.0.1 - - [06/Oct/2019 19:57:32] "GET /upload.php?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=ubuntu.ttf HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

I can't figure out why the index page now fails to load.

Here is the code for the **uploaded.html** page in question, already built by someone else.

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block head %}
    {{ super() }}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <body>
    <img src="http://diagnijmegen.nl/images/b/bd/Xray.jpg" alt="Italian Trulli">

                    <!-- {{ predictions }} -->
                    <style>
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Results</h2>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Disease</th>
    <th>Percent Likelihood</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Pneumonia</td>
    <td>98%</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Fibrosis</td>
    <td>43%</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>


{% endblock %}
```

And this is the code for the view (**main.py**):

```
from flask import render_template, jsonify, Flask, redirect, url_for, request
from app import app
import random
import os
from keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.applications.resnet50 import preprocess_input, decode_predictions
import numpy as np


@app.route('/')

#disease_list = ['Atelectasis', 'Consolidation', 'Infiltration', 'Pneumothorax', 'Edema', 'Emphysema', \
                  # 'Fibrosis', 'Effusion', 'Pneumonia', 'Pleural_Thickening', 'Cardiomegaly', 'Nodule', 'Mass', \
                  # 'Hernia']

@app.route('/upload')
def upload_file2():
   return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/uploaded', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
   if request.method == 'POST':
      f = request.files['file']
      path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], f.filename)
      model= ResNet50(weights='imagenet')
      img = image.load_img(path, target_size=(224,224))
      x = image.img_to_array(img)
      x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
      x = preprocess_input(x)
      preds = model.predict(x)
      preds_decoded = decode_predictions(preds, top=3)[0] 
      print(decode_predictions(preds, top=3)[0])
      f.save(path)
      return render_template('uploaded.html', title='Success', predictions=preds_decoded, user_image=f.filename)


@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', title='Home')

@app.route('/map')
def map():
    return render_template('map.html', title='Map')


@app.route('/map/refresh', methods=['POST'])
def map_refresh():
    points = [(random.uniform(48.8434100, 48.8634100),
               random.uniform(2.3388000, 2.3588000))
              for _ in range(random.randint(2, 9))]
    return jsonify({'points': points})


@app.route('/contact')
def contact():
    return render_template('contact.html', title='Contact')
```

I have read the tutorial multiple times, and I have no idea why it is not working. 
Obviously the error is on the **uplodaded.html** file, but I don't know exactly where I must modify the code. If I change something, or I use as reference others .htmls from others exercises I get more (and different) errors.

I'm posting the "original" code, the one used in the tutorial. They show us that it's works. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable the module:

```
from flask_wtf.csrf import CsrfProtect
CsrfProtect(app)
```

Read more about it in the [documentation](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/csrf.html).